# Fill an HTML field with Local datetime and name of time zone

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can an html field be auto filled with a local date time with the name of the time zone beside it.

HTML field:

```
<tr>
<td>
<label for="date">Date & Time :</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="date" name="date">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you try [`new Date()`](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/vxer5L4x/) ?

Comment: `<input type=date name=date>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your input field an ID:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="your-id">
```

and than you can just do

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("your-id").value = Date().toString();
</script>`
```

Without giving it an ID you would have to do

```
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].value
```

but you have to be sure there is only one input with name `date`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will help you to fill up the date.

```
<input  type="date" name="date" id="date">  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    document.getElementById("date").value = Date().toString();  
</script>
```